# How to get ppg value with max30105 sensor

Tags: python, linux, hardware, sensors, heartrate

I want to get ppg value to max30105.

But i can't find ppg value in code.

Just i find heart rate.

How to get ppg value?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# NOTE! This code should not be used for medical diagnosis. It's
# for fun/novelty use only, so bear that in mind while using it.

import time
from max30105 import MAX30105, HeartRate

max30105 = MAX30105()
max30105.setup(leds_enable=2)

max30105.set_led_pulse_amplitude(1, 0.2)
max30105.set_led_pulse_amplitude(2, 12.5)
max30105.set_led_pulse_amplitude(3, 0)

max30105.set_slot_mode(1, 'red')
max30105.set_slot_mode(2, 'ir')
max30105.set_slot_mode(3, 'off')
max30105.set_slot_mode(4, 'off')


def display_heartrate(beat, bpm, avg_bpm):
    print("{} BPM: {:.2f}  AVG: {:.2f}".format("<3" if beat else "  ",
          bpm, avg_bpm))


hr = HeartRate(max30105)

print("""
NOTE! This code should not be used for medical diagnosis. It's
for fun/novelty use only, so bear that in mind while using it.
This example shows a readout of your heart rate in BPM (beats per
minute) and heartbeats detected using a heart emoticon <3.
It's best to hold the sensor against your fingertip (the fleshy side)
using a piece of wire or a rubber band looped through the mounting
holes on the breakout, as the sensor is very sensitive to small
movements and it's hard to hold your finger against the sensor with
even pressure.
If you're using your MAX30105 Breakout with Breakout Garden, then
we'd recommend using one of our Breakout Garden Extender Kits with
some female-to-female jumper jerky.
https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/breakout-garden-extender-kit
""")

delay = 10

print("Starting readings in {} seconds...\n".format(delay))
time.sleep(delay)

try:
    hr.on_beat(display_heartrate, average_over=4)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

In this code, can get heartrate.

But, I want get PPG value.

I using this library.

https://github.com/pimoroni/max30105-python

I've been analyzing library.

Thanks.